# Giving QML a QSharedPointer<T> or a std::unique_ptr<T>?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, ownership

According to [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#data-ownership), "When data is transferred from C++ to QML, the ownership of the data always remains with C++. The exception to this rule is when a `QObject` is returned from an explicit C++ method call: in this case, the QML engine assumes ownership of the object, unless the ownership of the object has explicitly been set to remain with C++ by invoking `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership()` with `QQmlEngine::CppOwnership` specified."

As a C++ programmer, whenever I see a function return a raw pointer, I shudder. Why return a `Foo*` when you could return a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` or at least a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` or a `QSharedPointer<Foo>`? It seems like this functionality isn't built in. Obviously QML should be allowed to take a `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`. Is taking a `QSharedPointer<Foo>` really not supported? Is there some work-around?

Maybe something like this (inspired by http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#value-types)?

```
template <typename T>
class QSharedNotNullPointerWrapper {
{
    Q_GADGET
    Q_PROPERTY(T& value READ value WRITE setValue)
public:
    QSharedNotNullPointerWrapper(const QSharedPointer<T>& ptr) 
        : m_ptr(ptr) {
        Q_ASSERT(m_ptr); // Not-null
    }
    operator QSharedPointer<T>&() { return m_ptr; }
    const T& value() const { return *m_ptr; }
          T& value()       { return *m_ptr; }
    void setValue(const T &val) { *m_ptr = val; }   
private:
    QSharedPointer<T> m_ptr;
};

#define DECLARE_SHARED_PINTER_METATYPE(NAME, T) \
  using NAME = QSharedNotNullPointerWrapper<T>; \
  Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(NAME)
```

If something like that works, then I could do

```
DECLARE_SHARED_PINTER_METATYPE(MyFooPtr, Foo)
```

and then have a function return a `MyFooPtr` and safely hand it to QML or to C++.

Comment: Assuming `Foo` is a Q_GADGET: Shure, this would work. Simply register the created type in QML using `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<MyFooPtr>("uri", 1, 0, "MyFooPtr");` (of course only as long as Foo is also registered that way)

Comment: refer to these two bug tickets: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35404 and https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43080 ...and be sure to note the `sharedFromThis()` idea on one of the links